# How to interpret the raw data from microphone on Android for conducting on-the-fly FFT?

Tags: android, microphone, on-the-fly, raw-data

I am trying to access the microphone on Android phone and retrieve the raw data(not write to files). But after I wrote raw data to files, I can not play the audio I record(use Matlab to replay it). I am wondering is there any parameter I need to adjust or the process has some problems?  Thanks a lot.

```
     AudioManager audio_service = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audio_service.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
        audio_service.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
        audio_service.setRouting(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL, AudioManager.ROUTE_EARPIECE, AudioManager.ROUTE_ALL);

        int iSampleRate = AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
        int iAudioBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(iSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
         recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.CAMCORDER, iSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, iAudioBufferSize);
         recorder.startRecording();
         bRecording = true;
         recordThread.start();



     public void run()
            {
                    short[] buffer = new short[iAudioBufferSize];
                android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

            while(!interrupted())
            {
                // Make sure the audiorecorder get the enough data
                ReadFully(buffer, 0, iAudioBufferSize,recorder);                  

                try{                 
                    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length-1; i++)
                    {                      
                            if(rawAudioWriter1 != null){
                                rawAudioWriter1.append(Short.toString(buffer[i]));
                                rawAudioWriter1.append('\n');                            
                            }                                                                               
                    }
                    if(rawAudioWriter1 !=null){                     
                        rawAudioWriter1.flush();
                    }


                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}

        void readFully(short[] data, int off, int length, AudioRecord mrecorder) {
            int read;
            while (length > 0) {
                read = mrecorder.read(data, off, length);
                length -= read;
                off += read;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly does _"I can not play the audio"_ mean? Have you tried importing the raw data into a sound editor (like Audacity)? Also, don't use `setRouting`. It's been deprecated since Android 1.6 (and is probably not even implemented on most recent Android versions).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I loaded data to mat lab and use wavplay() function to play out the raw data. The generated sound was not right. I think it might be casued by the incorrect sample rate. But I am not sure